# Dynamic class attribute generation

Tags: python

This code works as expected, but can it cause a memory leak?

```
class Method(object):
    method = []
    def call(self,method,*args,**kwargs):
       kwargs.update({'access_token': self.access_token})
       print method,args,kwargs
    def __getattr__(self,name):
       cp = Method()
       cp.access_token = self.access_token
       cp.method = self.method + [name]
       return cp
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       return self.call('.'.join(self.method),*args,**kwargs)

class Api(Method):
    access_token = 'setups on init'

a=Api()
a.get()
a.set(data=1)
```

Or will Method instance go to garbage after calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a memory leak.

You are simply returning a callable object; when you no longer reference it it'll be cleaned up automatically.

The `__getattr__` method doesn't add any more references to the object other than the local variable name. That reference is cleared when the function exits.

The `a.get()` and `a.set()` expressions only hold a reference to the object for long enough to look up the `__call__` method and invoke it. When the `__call__` method returns, the number of references to the `Method()` instance drops to 0 and the object is cleared.

Comment: Even if i call `a.friends.get_related()` (may be up to 5)? Will all instaces (except a) be cleaned?

Comment: @eri: yes, because all references by the interpreter are temporary and are properly cleared. Note that regular Python methods are wrapper objects too (see the [descriptor howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)) and if there were any memory leaks in calling expressions Python would have died from a million memory leak problems years ago. :-)